# Why does unique(x, by = a) work on data.tables but ignore the by = a on tibbles?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

When using `unique()` on a tibble it silently drops the by argument. (I assume.) I do not understand why this is the case and why there is **no error message**. This is my example:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

test_tb <- data.table(a = c("a", "a", "b"), b = c(1, 2, 3))
test_tib <- tibble(a = c("a", "a", "b"), b = c(1, 2, 3))
test_tb
test_tib
unique(test_tb, by = c("a"))
unique(test_tib, by = c("a"))
```

I would assume that both would behave in a simmilar manner but that is not the case:

```
> unique(test_tb, by = c("a"))
   a b
1: a 1
2: b 3
> unique(test_tib, by = c("a"))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  a         b
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 a         2
3 b         3
```

Is this expected behaviour and should I always add an `as.data.table` when using `unique()` and other functions from the data.table library? What is best practice in this case?

Comment: unique is an S3 generic. Only the data.table method has a by argument. However, because the generic has … as an argument, you don’t get an error if you pass by but the first argument isn’t a data.table.

Comment: `dplyr::distinct(test_tib, a, .keep_all = TRUE)` seems to be the tibble equivalent.

Comment: you should try `distinct` from dplyr [link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html)

Comment: Thank you I do know how to work around it, I was only very angry at wasting a lot of time finding this, as its silent. Turns out it was my mistake with the generic ooops. @Roland 's answer is all that was needed.

Comment: Unfortunately there are several "small annoyances" between classes `data.frame`, `data.table`, and `tbl_df`. Top of the list for me: `x[,cols,drop=]` and this `unique` thing.